# adding an argument from the map method to the foreach method using Java Stream

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I wrote a tiny example to explain my problem:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class Example {

     public static void main( String[] args )  {
         String [] array =  {"1 0101 5","1 0101 5"};
         Arrays.stream(array)
               .map(str->str.split(" "))//every String is mapped to an array of String
               .map(arr-> returnAListOf5Element( Integer.parseInt(arr[0]),arr[1],Integer.parseInt(arr[2])))
               .forEach(list-> tesMyList(list));//i want to send the Integer.parseInt(arr[2]) as a second argument
     }
    /**
     *
     * test if the list has size of 5
     */
    private static void testMyList(List<Integer> myList) {
         if (myList.size()==5)
             System.out.println("Ok");
    }

    /**
     *
     * return a list of 5 element
     * @return
     */
    private static List<Integer> returnAListOf5Element( int i, String s, int i1 ) {
         List list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
         return list;
    }
}
```

So I have some Strings like "1 0101 5","1 0101 5"....., i use stream operation to make some calcul.

The problem is i want to add the argument arr[2] found in the map method to the *testMyList* method found in the foreach method.

the method *testMyList* should be like:

```
 private static void testMyList(List<Integer> myList, int size) {
         if (myList.size()==size)
             System.out.println("Ok");
    }
```

Comment: Easiest thing is probably to collapse the `.map.map.forEach` into a single `forEach` that does all three things. (then you don't really need the stream anymore and can just use a for-in loop over the array.

Comment: Another option is to have the second `map` step return both its real output and that extra integer you need for the next step (either as a pair of these two things or maybe as an array with now six elements).

Comment: yes i see a discution about mapping to two element, but i found the solution more complicated than the normal for loop.

Comment: Third option could "zip" together two streams, one with your arrays, and one with the integers. Must be careful that they exactly correspond to each-other in the sequence of these two streams.

Comment: why returnAListOf5Element is accepting arguments but not doing anything with them ?

Comment: Streams are mostly useful when you need to compose different parts together, especially when receiving them as parameters. If you have all the logic in one place already, you don't really need them.

Comment: @grsdev7 because i made a tiny example, my real program is big than that and i'm willing to simplify thing so you could understand.

Comment: @grsdev7 normally returnAListOf5Element is method in another class with huge calculation.and it is not useful to add no useful thing on my example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see three possible solutions:

1. `returnAListOf5Element`  returns `arr[2]` within the list. (let's say, by contact, it's the last element in the returned list.) *It's a dirty approach.*
2. `map` returns a `Map.Entry<List<Integer>, Integer>` which is composed of the result of the `returnAListOf5Element(...)` call and `arr[2]`. *It's a more reasonable way.*

These two ides are based on caching state of a previous operation so you can get it at a next one. It's the only way to obtain the result calculated in the chain before.

3. You replace the stream chain with a simple loop where each intermediate calculation is accessible.

I find the last method the most simple and performance-wise. It doesn't seem that you are going to reap any benefits from streams here. I would stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own class to maintain your data rather than using some generic one like `List`.

```
class MyObject {
    public final int i;
    public final String string;
    public final int i1;
    public MyObject(int i, String string, int i1){
        this.i = i;
        this.string = string;
        this.i1 = i1;
    }
    public static MyObject parse(String line) {
        String[] split = line.split(" ");
        return new MyObject(Integer.parseInt(split[0], split[1], Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
Files.lines(filename)
     .map(MyObject::parse)  // now you have a Stream of MyObjects
     .forEach(o -> verify(o));
```

with eg

```
void verify(MyObject object) {
    if (object.i1 < 5) {
        System.out.println("invalid");
    }
}
```